# Issue with fetching the data on group by on Mysql on multiple one to many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently we are having three tables

**users**(used to store the basic information)

- id -> PK
- firstname -> Index
- lastname -> Index

And we have many more fields in this table usually used for filter the data

---

**user_titles** (which is one to many relation table with Table A. WHich we are normally using to store the titles of the users on table A. A single users can have multiple titles out of that one can be primary and another can be 
secondary)

- id
- user_id(FK to table A)
- title_id(FK to title table, which we are storing all title names)
- is_primary(enum->'primary','secondary')

---

**user_speciality**(Table is a one to many relation with user table where we are storing the primary specialty and additional specialty of the users)

- id -> PK
- user_id -> (FK, refernce to user table)
- specialty_id -> (FK, reference to specialty table where we are storing the specialty information)
- is_primary -> (enum ->'primary','secondary')

So above is the table stricture we have and on search we have to list all users with the selected speciality and titles.

Based on this table structure we are fetching the data as below query

```
> SELECT `user_titles`.`title_id`,`user_titles`.`is_primary`,`user_speciality`.`speciality_id`,`user_speciality`.`is_primary`,`users`.`firstname`,`users`.`lastname`FROM `users`, `user_titles`,`user_speciality` where `user_speciality`.`user_id`=`users`.`id` and `user_titles`.`user_id`=`users`.`id`
```

But when we are listing the data we are getting multiple rows for users if users have secondary titles or specialty. Basically i need the data to be in below format.

When we are using group_concat the above query we are getting an error which says `group_concat` or `group by` cannot possible.

```
user_id, title_id(primary), title_ids(secondary titles with comma seperated), user.firstname, user.lastname, speciality_id(primary), specialty_id(secondary id's with comma separated)
```

We could easily get this structure if we are storing the titles and specialty id's in user table with comma separated valued and write a like query, but we have huge amount of data and doubtful the performance of a like query over these bunch of data.

Please guide us to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

That said, what you want is aggregation.  In particular, you can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT u.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ut.is_primary THEN ut.title_id END) as primary_title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NOT ut.is_primary THEN ut.title_id END) as secondary_titles,
       MAX(CASE WHEN us.is_primary THEN us.speciality_id END) as primary_specialty,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NOT us.is_primary THEN us.speciality_id END) as secondary_specialties
FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN
     `user_titles` ut
     ON ut.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     `user_speciality` us
     ON us.`user_id`= u.`id` 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: Sorry Worked. Thanks a lot.